# Unity DI update to version 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have updated my DI from Unity 4 to version 5 which is the current stable version. From that moment on my project started throwing exceptions like "The current type, System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?"

Multiple exceptions are thrown for different ASP.NET MVC types. Before the update everything was working fine. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Strange in the repository for version 5.x they stated that namespaces has been changed https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity, but this error is more of runtime then compiletime?

Comment: Might want to remove the word "Microsoft" from the title. They gave up on Unity 2 years ago. See [The future of Unity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/).

Comment: @vasiloreshenski It's a runtime error. All namespaces were changed and simplified. If you directly update in nuget package manager from version 4 to 5 it starts throwing all these mvc related exceptions.

Comment: Same here with ASP.NET Web API. I also had to update Unity.WebAPI package but Unity can't still resolve my stuff :(

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I just had to add [Unity.Container](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Container/) to my project.